# Como obter resposta de comunicação utilizando MQTT

Tags: java, arduino, mqtt

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação a qual utilizo o protocolo de comunicação MQTT, onde meu sistema manda um comando para um determinado equipamento, o meu equipamento esta recebendo o comando e alterando o status. O problema é: como receber o feedback do meu equipamento? Pois meu sistema precisa receber de volta se o equipamento mudou de status e qual o status atual para que seja exibido no meu sistema.

Minha classe MQTT `package business;

```
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;

public class Mqtt implements MqttCallback {

private static Mqtt INSTANCE;

MqttClient client;
//String ipPatchPanel;
//String mensagem = "D" + "numeroPorta" + "comando";
String topico = "Stream";

private Mqtt() throws MqttException {
    client = new MqttClient("tcp://192.168.1.105:1883", "Enviando...");
    client.connect();
    client.setCallback(this);
}

//Singleton
public static Mqtt getInstance() throws MqttException {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        return new Mqtt();
    } else {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}

public void comandoMqtt(String ip, String porta, String comando) {
    try {
        String comandos = ip + "&" + porta + "&" + comando; // string que recebe e concatena três parâmetros recebidos na função
        client.subscribe(topico);//tópico de subscrição é o mesmo valor do IP
        MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();
        message.setPayload(comandos.getBytes());
        client.publish(topico, message);//tópico onde publica é o mesmo valor do ip e o outro parâmetro é a mensagem
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(message);
}

@Override
public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

`E meu MQTT-Arduino:`#include 
    #include 
    #include

```
// Update these with values suitable for your network.
byte mac[]    = {  0xDE, 0xED, 0xBA, 0xFE, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 122);
IPAddress server(192, 168, 1, 117);
char mensagem;
int ledAmarelo = 3;
int ledVerde = 4;

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
Serial.print("Message arrived [");
Serial.print(topic);
Serial.print("] ");
for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
mensagem = (char)payload[i];
Serial.print((char)payload[i]);

if(mensagem == "ativoAmarelo"){
  Serial.println("Led Amarelo Ativado");
  digitalWrite(ledAmarelo, HIGH);
}
if(mensagem == "ativoVerde"){
  Serial.println("Led Verde Ativado");
  digitalWrite(ledVerde, HIGH);
}
}
Serial.println();
}

EthernetClient ethClient;
PubSubClient client(ethClient);

void reconnect() {
// Loop until we're reconnected
while (!client.connected()) {
Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
// Attempt to connect
if (client.connect("arduinoClient")) {
  Serial.println("connected");
  // Once connected, publish an announcement...
  client.publish("outTopic","hello world");
  // ... and resubscribe
  client.subscribe("inTopic");

} else {
  Serial.print("failed, rc=");
  Serial.print(client.state());
  Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
  // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
  delay(5000);
}
}
}

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(57600);

 client.setServer(server, 1883);
 client.setCallback(callback);

 Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
 // Allow the hardware to sort itself out
 delay(1500);
}

void loop()
{
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();
}
```

`

No console vejo o envio pegando o ip do equipamento e o comando correspondente ao botao clicado no sistema web. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu comando está chegando até o arduino e ele está mudando o status? Pergunto isso porque pelo seu código você está publicando em um tópico chamado `Stream` enquanto que o arduino está se subscrevendo a um tópico chamado `inTopic`. O tópico deveria ser o mesmo nos dois casos para que o comando publicado seja recebido pelo arduino.

Para a volta a mesma coisa, só que em um outro tópico, que pode ser o `outTopic` (o arduino publica nesse tópico e a classe `Mqtt` se subscreve nesse mesmo tópico).

A propósito, seu Singleton tem um pequeno bug: a variável `INSTANCE` nunca recebe o `new Mqtt()`.

Comment: ele esta chegando ate o arduino, porem estou com dificultade para tratar a string, que consequentemente fara o arduino mudar o status. @Piovezan voce tem algum exemplo completo dessa comunicação usando JAVA-Arduino? Nao domino esse protocolo, estou conhecendo agora.

Comment: Não tenho. Para tratar a string, como meu C está enferrujado, você deve procurar sobre comparação de strings nessa linguagem, ou lançar uma nova pergunta.